# MVC Push notification from server to client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, push-notification

This question may sound lame but.

Is there any technique to send push notificaiton from server to client side, regarding the server status.

For Example:
While Login

Notification in Client Side in sequence:

```
Validating User ...
Validating Digital Certificate ...
Sorting downloadable file ...
Preparing to download ...
```

If its not possible, then is there any alternative elegant way to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SignalR` :

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
            // Call the Send method on the hub. 
            chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
            // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
            $('#message').val('').focus();
        });
    });
```

use more info: [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

Answer (score 1):

you can use signalR here i am providing link have a look on it.

http://www.asp.net/signalr